# ion-avatar doesn't work but item-avatar does

Tags: ionic-framework

I am showing below the two versions of ionic code that I have written. The one which uses ion-avatar doesn't seem to work but if I use item-avatar it does.

This one doesn't work

```
<ion-list inset>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="leader in leaders" class="item item-text-wrap">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img ng-src="{{baseURL+leader.image}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{leader.name}}<h2>
        <h3>{{leader.designation}}</h3>
        <p>{{leader.description}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This one works

```
<ion-list inset>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="leader in leaders" class="item-avatar item-text-wrap">
        <img ng-src="{{baseURL+leader.image}}">
        <h2>{{leader.name}}<h2>
        <h3>{{leader.designation}}</h3>
        <p>{{leader.description}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

While my code is fine and working, I am wondering why the first one doesn't work. I have ionic 2.2.1 installed.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: If your are using ionic 2, did you try using `[src]="{{baseURL+leader.image}}"` ?

Comment: I tried using that and it didn't work. How can I tell I am using ionic 2 ? ionic --v tells me - 2.2.1. I used ionic serve --lab

Comment: @shirishc please read documentation  clearly. `ionic -v` gives you the version of ionic cli not project version

Comment: Apologies. My first ionic project....OK. thanks, Will look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ion-avatar` is implemented in `ionic2` version where as `item-avatar` is `ionic1` compatible.

You might be using `ion-avatar` in a `v1` app that is the reason for error.

you can check official docs for `list-item` here

[ionic-2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#avatar-list)

[ionic v1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#item-avatars)

Comment: How can I tell I am using ionic 2 ? ionic --v tells me - 2.2.1. I used ionic serve --lab to run the client side.

Comment: how did you created ionic project? did you used `--v2` in the command?